# routing controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My routes.php as Below:

```
$controller_list = array('showmenu','aboutus'); // etc you will have        to put all your controllers in this array

foreach($controller_list as $controller_name)
{
     $route[$controller_name] = $controller_name;
     $route[$controller_name.'/(:any)'] = $controller_name.'/$1';
}
$route['([a-zA-z_]+)'] = 'main/index/$1';
//$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I want to call all controller in main class like                localhost/foldername/main/about(different slugs)
how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

i exactly don't understand what you want to say but you can define each function separately in your routes.php for simple and fine url like this:

```
$route['whatever you want in your url'] = 'your controller name/your function name';
```

this will like:

```
localhost/foldername/(different slugs)
```

Comment: You have to do it separately for all functions

Comment: Actually I have same class but different controllers.like in my main.php controller file there are so many methods like showmenu and showmenu call a different view page another is aboutus method call a different view...so how to maintain same url for all methods

Comment: It is important that showmenu method calls different slugs dynamiccally but the view layout is same.so the problem is when i dynamically add the slugs the url would be localhost/foldername/main/showmenu/slugs..but the other page url is localhost/foldername/main/slugs

Comment: can you share your code snippet for better understanding

Comment: try this whatever
$route['your custom slug'] = '/main/showmenu/slugs';
$route['your custom slug'] = 'main/slugs';

Comment: And set your default controller first
$default_controller = "main";

Answer (score 0):

```
      if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
     exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Main extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model("menu_model");
     $this->load->model("main_model");
}

public function index() {


     $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');


    $this->load->view('vwHeader',$data);//Left Menu


}

 public function showmenu()
{
     $menutitle = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $query = $this->db->get_where('category',array('namecategory'=>$menutitle));
      $data['content'] = $this->main_model->show_content($menutitle);

    $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');

    $this->load->view('vwMain',$data);//Left Menu
}
 public function menu()
{
    $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');

    $this->load->view('vwHeader',$data);//Left Menu
}



       public function aboutus() {

       $arr['page'] ='about';
         $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');


    $this->load->view('vwHeader',$data);//Left Menu
    $this->load->view('vwAboutus',$arr);
}

         public function contactus() {

       $arr['page'] ='contactus';
         $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');


    $this->load->view('vwHeader',$data);//Left Menu
    $this->load->view('vwContactus',$arr);
}


 }
```

This is controller main.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this first you have to set your default controller

```
$default_controller = "main";
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
```

then you have to define your methods

```
$route['same url'] = 'aboutus';
$route['same url'] = 'showmenu';
```

Comment: what should i write in the place same url

Comment: whatever you want the keyword in your url that will same when your aboutus and showmenu will call

Comment: and if you don't want to set main as your default controller in ths case you have to write like this:   $route['same url'] = 'main/aboutus';
$route['same url'] = 'main/showmenu'

Comment: $default_controller = "main";
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route['main/aboutus'] = 'aboutus';
$route['main/slug'] = 'showmenu';

Comment: oo you do it opposite  $route['aboutus'] = 'main/aboutus'; $routes['showmenu']= 'main/slug'

Comment: i can't see a slug function in your class

Comment: but when i give the url that localhost/foldername/main/slug   then the page is not found shown..actually showmenu function controlls to fetch data dynamically

Comment: exactly because you have changed your url   localhost/foldername/slug

Comment: give the re-write url   localhost/foldername/slug

Comment: slug is the keyword you entered in routes.php m i right?

Comment: routes.php  $default_controller = "main";
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route['aboutus'] = 'main/aboutus';
 $route['main/slug'] = 'showmenu';

Comment: share your routes.php

Comment: this is my routes.php                                                                                               $default_controller = "main"; $route['default_controller'] = $default_controller; $route['aboutus'] = 'main/aboutus'; $route['main/slug'] = 'showmenu';

Comment: i can't see slug method in your controller

Comment: it should be like that     $route['slug'] = 'showmenu'

Comment: and $route['aboutus] = 'aboutus'

Comment: if you share your routes.php i can update it for you

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.php

```
$default_controller = "main";
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;

$route['aboutus'] = 'aboutus';
$route['slug'] = 'showmenu';

$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```